# How do I modify this procedure to read in a variable length string using Interrupt I/O not polling?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm confused on this. How do I go about changing this procedure?

[image: Problem/code in picture]

Answer (score 2):

This code you have shown is not using polling.  It is using blocking I/O to get one character at a time.  The underlying system is using an exception handler to buffer keystroke data so that the user program can request a character of input whenever it wants.  If there's no characters available, the `getc` will block — there's no polling.  It already is using interrupt I/O!

Polling involves looping but looping does not necessarily imply polling.

The looping here is taking characters, one at a time, and, the looping stops when a newline character is entered.

Polling would repeatedly test an I/O flag (in a loop) and when the flag says that I/O is ready, would get the keyboard character (and clear the flag).  That polling loop would then be nested within an outer loop as described in the above paragraph, storing characters in user space until a newline is entered.

---

If you want to do a non-blocking check to see if there is any keyboard data ready, that is another matter, and could be done with a properly configured read call.  Such might tell you how many characters are ready, so if zero then your program can go do something else for a while.

---

You might be able to set up a `signal` handler that will run in response to keyboard I/O ready, and capture the character that has just come in.